# Cefsharp how to get current URL address? c#

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I want to get the current address and basically put it in a textbox. 
I found this link but can't seem to understand anything.

http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_Address.htm

I would really appreciate a code snippet from someone. It's killing me. 
i'm using WFA.

Comment: Please share your efforts so far, some code for example.

Comment: I have the browser that's working fine https://puu.sh/wuFOg/3ac3a28bda.png

Thing is, I want to verify if the link is redirected to one place or another = if the user is logger in or not. (it's a bit weird :) )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to listen to below address change event and persists it yourself.

```
this.Browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
this.Browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;

private void Browser_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.CurrentAddress = e.Address;
        }
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an "AddressChanged" event in the latest version for me..?

Answer (score 2):

The browser object exposes the address using the property **Address**:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(...);
var currentAddress = browser.Address;
```

Comment: I did not found the browser.Address property on version 57, is it on older versions.

Comment: @Pravin: It should still be avaliable in version 57: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_Wpf_ChromiumWebBrowser_Address.htm

Comment: @Chrille There is no property called Address in version 67, how to get the DocumentComplete like webbrowser.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using version 71 and the method:

```
TextBox1.Text = browser.Address;
```

Seems to work. Try updating to 71 and see if that helps, if you still have a problem with this.

"browser" is obviously the CefSharp browser control I've added programmatically.
If you don't know how to do this, it's merely the following:

```
CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("https://google.com/");
```

Comment: I don't see it in the Intellisense dropdown, but the property is there.  Must have the `Browsable(False)` property attribute.